# Horizontally scrollable cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make horizontally scrollable cards(divs) with only one card is visible at a time and the the scroll bar can't stop between two cards.
(Using Html, css and js)
[Homepage of airbnb, which features the result I look to reach.](https://www.airbnb.com)

Comment: sorry for only a link, but look at the  "new" css property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-snap-type/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent div and set its `overflow: auto;` and place all card divs under it aligned inline.

Or i would suggest using a slider for this if you should
[Slick slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)

Comment: Can you explain further, please?